# How to custom transition for each component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions, vuejs-transition

I have 3 components which I want to show a transition effect when they enter/leave.

There's 1 "main" component and the 2 others show up when you press the associated button. My current sample code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/5aq1k05L/

```
<transition :name="'step_' + currentView" mode="out-in">
  <component :is="currentView"></component>
</transition>
```

CSS:

```
.step_componentA-enter-active {
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.step_componentA-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0s;
}

.step_componentA-enter {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.step_mainComponent-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.step_mainComponent-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.step_componentB-enter-active {
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.step_componentB-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0s;
}

.step_componentB-enter {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

**What I am trying to do:**

When I click on the "componentA" button, I want that component to slide from the left while "mainComponent" is still visible in the background (not stripped out of elements like now) during the transition.

Same thing for "componentB", except it will slide from the right, and will back to the right when clicking back.

What am I missing? https://jsfiddle.net/5aq1k05L/

Comment: @tony19 Indeed. I've updated the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

Here a working example with the `componentA` and `componentB` that are sliding over the `mainComponent` -> https://jsfiddle.net/5aq1k05L/8/

I changed the transition to `mode:in-out`, I added a `z-index` for each component, and put the components in `position:absolute` and the app in `position:relative`

---

**Edit:**

Here a working example for your case -> https://jsfiddle.net/5aq1k05L/4/

---

When you analyse the script step by step, you see that the class when the `componentB` is leaving is `step_mainComponent-leave-active step_mainComponent-leave-to` that it makes a classic toggle relative to the `mainComponent` style.

If you want to use different animations, you should use `enter-active-class` and `leave-active-class` etc (see more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Custom-Transition-Classes)) - or put two vars in `name`, i guess, with a dynamic value relative to the previous view, in the store like `currentView` is.

It could be like this :

```
<transition
    :name="'step_' + currentView + '_from_' + prevView" 
    mode="out-in"
  >
```

In the store (you ll need to update the states, mapState, etc.. as well too) :

```
SET_CURRENT_VIEW(state, new_currentView) {
  state.prevView = state.currentView;
  state.currentView = new_currentView;
}
```

Hope it ll help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure if I understood. I guess I can see how that would help with the sliding from different direction, but how about the previous component "losing" its elements before being removed?

Comment: The concept would be to make the `:leave-active-class` different for each prev component because in your case, the `step_mainComponent` is the "idle" class that makes the toggle effect, i mean `transform: translateX(-100%);` translate at the left side only, not the right one.
What didnt you understand precisely ?

Comment: I think understand the concept and added the previousView state, but I still don't get it to show a different animation when triggering from componentB and componentA plus keeping the background

Comment: @Cornwell, i did it as well, see the example

Comment: @Cornwell did you see the example ? Its working as you want :-)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply, I missed the notification somehow. I still seem to be unable to get part of it working: Where the main component should not "disappear" before the other one slides in. Meaning: I should see the main component in the background while the new component slides in, instead of just a gray background like now. I tried messing with the opacity but no luck

Comment: @Cornwell Ok, see the **Edit 2**, i think it's what you want. Don't forget to accept or add a point ;-)